# How best to backup My Documents (maybe with Git?)

Tags: windows, backup, git, version-control

I would like a good process to backup My Documents on my hard drive periodically to an external hard drive or repository.  I want to have a snap shot at each backup period, and don't want to waste space by copying identical files each time.

I am thinking of using Git.

The typical files are MS Word documents and the like and not text documents, so I won't have the benefit of seeing exactly what was changed, but at least I would have a snapshot of the hard drive at each backup.

Is this a good strategy?  If so, any suggestions how to best implement?  If not, why not and what would be better?

Thanks

Comment: Why not use shadow copies on the external hard drive and a scheduled task to copy the contents of your "My Documents" folder to the external drive on a specified time period?

Comment: What about using Dropbox?  It automatically backs up everything more or less continuously.

Answer (score 1):

Windows has a built-in feature called File History / Previous Versions that do exactly what you're asking. You don't need any 3rd-party tools.

If you're in Windows 8, search from Start for `File History Settings` to get started. There's a short article on getting started with it [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/set-drive-file-history).

If you're in Windows 7, you can enable Shadow Copy / Previous Versions to get file versioning. Although it's possible to offload old copies to a secondary drive, this isn't as straightforward as it should be. I would just combine previous versions with nightly backups, and this pretty easily configurable from control panel.

Answer (score 0):

I've had very good experiences with [Allway Sync](https://allwaysync.com/).  It installs onto your local machine, and has a free version that's quite powerful.  I use it to keep folders synchronized (in both directions) between two machines, using a USB key as an intermediary.

However, you could just configure it as a one-way backup, and could either schedule the sync or have it automatically happen every time you plugged in your external drive.  It can keep databases of old document revisions, etc.

It can also sync over networks, but I haven't used it for that.

Good luck :)